# Rounded ProgressBar with Loading.... Text in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I want to use the `progress bar with rounded circle` and with `loading....` text in my application. I have searched more. But still not getting the clear idea.

**Default Bar:**

[image]

**Expected Bar:**

[image]

Note: I want to do this only in xml file for webview. Could anybody please help me

Comment: Why not use [Progress Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)??

Comment: Progress Dialog shows a circle like you want in newer versions of Android (I believe ICS onwards) and a spinner like the one you don't want on previous versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You should code your custom [webview client](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) where you can implement your logic to show custom dialog on page load and hide on page finish.*

Take a look at [Android WebView and the Indeterminant Progress Solution](http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2010/05/04/android-webview-and-the-indeterminant-progress-solution/)

```
I want to do this only in xml file for webview. Could anybody please help me
```

What does it mean? Do you want to change the UI of progress bar?

*If yes then take a look at my blog for [Customization of circular progress bar](http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/customization-of-spinner-progress/), which can help you to change the UI.*

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code :

Layout : main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llProgress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Code : MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private LinearLayout llProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    llProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProgress);
    showProgress("Loading...");
}

private void showProgress(String message) {
    ((TextView) llProgress.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage)).setText(message);
    llProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

private void hideProgress() {
    ((TextView) llProgress.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage)).setText("");
    llProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

}
```

Answer (score -2):

**`MyProgressDialog.class`** :- The Class that will return circular dialog while called.

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MyProgressDialog extends Dialog {
public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message) {
    return show(context, title, message, false);
}

public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate) {
    return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, false, null);
}

public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable) {
    return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, cancelable, null);
}

public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate,
        boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    MyProgressDialog dialog = new MyProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
    /* The next line will add the ProgressBar to the dialog. */
    dialog.addContentView(new ProgressBar(context), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    dialog.show();

    return dialog;
}

public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.NewDialog);
}
}
```

**NewDialog's** Style that should be putted in the **`String.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!--=====This is the Style for the progressBar====================  -->
  <style name="NewDialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
<!--============================================== -->
</resource>
```

### Now,How to call this **`ProgressDialog`** ?? It's this Way:-

```
Dialog pd;   // Declare it on the Top of the Activity using it to make it Global.  

//Start of Dialog
pd=MyProgressDialog.show(ActivityName.this, "Loading", "");     

// To Stop the Dialog
pd.dismiss();
```